# Embed youtube comments and like

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I was wondering if it's possible to embed youtube videos' comments and like button with the video? 
If there is such thing, how can I do that or where can I get more info? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see an example of how to get and display the video comments

[Getting Youtube Video Information using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194619/getting-youtube-video-information-using-javascript-jquery)

and in the Topic Explorer project you can see how to add a 'like' or add the video to your favorites:

https://code.google.com/p/yt-topic-explorer/source/browse/app/views/main.html

```
<button ng-click="addToList($event.target, 'likes', videoResult.id)">{{'LIKE'|i18n}}</button>
<button ng-click="addToList($event.target, 'favorites', videoResult.id)">{{'FAVORITE'|i18n}}</button>
```

and in:

https://code.google.com/p/yt-topic-explorer/source/browse/app/scripts/controllers/main.js

```
$scope.addToList = function(target, listName, videoId) {
    var listId = $rootScope.relatedPlaylists[listName];

    target.textContent = topicExplorerApp.filter.i18n('ADDING');
    target.disabled = true;

    youtube({
      method: 'POST',
      service: 'playlistItems',
      params: {
        part: 'snippet'
      },
      body: {
        snippet: {
          playlistId: listId,
          resourceId: {
            kind: constants.VIDEO_KIND,
            videoId: videoId
          }
        }
      },
      callback: function(results) {
        if ('error' in results) {
          target.textContent = 'Error';
        } else {
          target.textContent = topicExplorerApp.filter.i18n('ADDED');
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

YouTube does not have any embed code that you can use to embed comments. So basically there are 2 options to embed comments -

**1.** Use the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) to embed and post comments. This will need a good coding knowledge.

To get comments use this endpoint

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads
```

To add comments use this endpoint

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems
```

**2.** Or you can use a ready-made plugin that allows this functionality. Here is a small [demo of the Youmax plugin](http://demos.codehandling.com/youmax/pro.html) that will list comments as well as allow you to add comments.

Comment: Your link to youmax plugin is broken.Seems like it is not maintained further

Comment: please check https://github.com/codehandling/youmax for 'youmax' as above demo link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:** On Feb,2016 YT has stopped the solution bellow from working :-( I'll keep it here just for reference

FOR THE COMMENTS:

As YT has deprecated the **gdata** for the comments url, you can scrape 'em also from here; its a workaround though :D

```
https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=cOIKAnF3mjs
```

...no authentication needed! :) and if you want to work the ***client side only*** (in this example by cross-domain), go through JS

```
<textarea style="width:100%;height:100%" id=cu></textarea>
<script>
var r='';
function c(d)
            {
            for(i=0;i<=d.query.count-1;i++)
               r=r+d.results[i];
            document.getElementById('cu').innerHTML=r;
            }
</script>
<script src="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%20SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=cOIKAnF3mjs%22&callback=c"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Access YouTube Comments by processing this URL

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$videoID}/comments`

The YouTube like functionality requires the user to be logged-in to his/hers Google account

Answer (score 0):

Adding the live chat could be done using 2 iframes.  One for the video stream and one for live chat.  Google has the documentation here.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en#zippy=%2Cembed-live-chat

```
<!-- video -->
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEO-ID>" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<!-- live chat -->
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=<VIDEO-ID>&embed_domain=www.example.com"></iframe>
```

The biggest trick is notice the `embed_domain=www.example.com` query parameter in the second iframe (for the Live Chat).  This needs to be set to the domain name that the iframes are embedded into.