# How do I embed a youTube video with its comments, likes and views on my html page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, youtube, comments

I have embeded other's videos, but how do I do it and bring in all of its likes,comments and views to my page. I want to allow visitors to also make comments and like it from my page without having to go to youtube.

Comment: [Use the youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

Comment: This should help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716005/embed-youtube-comments-and-like

Answer (score 0):

from my experience i don't think you can embed a video with the comments, but you can pull them using youtube api:

```
          //Retrieving comments for a video

//Each video entry contains a <gd:comments> tag, which encapsulates the URL to which you will send API requests to retrieve or append to the list of comments for the video. The sample XML below shows how this URL appears in an API response:

<feed>
  <entry>
    ...
    <media:group>
      ...
    </media:group>
    <gd:comments>
      <gd:feedLink
        href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments'/>
    </gd:comments>
  </entry>
</feed>

//Each comment has an author, a title and content. The following XML shows a sample API //response containing a comments feed:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
  xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'
  xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'
  xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'
  xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
  gd:etag='W/&quot;DE8HQXo-eip7ImA9WxRQGU4.&quot;'>
  <id>tag:youtube,2008:video:ZTUVgYoeN_b:comments</id>
  <updated>2008-07-18T22:10:57.065Z</updated>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
    term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment'/>
  <title>Comments on 'My Walk with Mr. Darcy'</title>
  <logo>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</logo>
  <link rel='related' type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b?v=2'/>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html'
    href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTUVgYoeN_b'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed'
    type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/comments?v=2'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post'
    type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/comments?v=2'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch'
    type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/comments/batch?v=2'/>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/comments?...'/>
  <link rel='service' type='application/atomsvc+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/comments?alt=atom-service&v=2'/>
  <link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml'
    href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/comments?...'/>
  <author>
    <name>YouTube</name>
    <uri>http://www.youtube.com/</uri>
  </author>
  <generator version='2.0'
    uri='http://gdata.youtube.com/'>YouTube data API</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults>9051</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry gd:etag='W/&quot;D0YASX47eCp7ImA9WxRQGU8.&quot;'>
    <id>tag:youtube,2008:video:xpI6VNvRTII:comment:F53EAC190E4EA5C9</id>
    <published>2008-07-18T14:57:59.000-07:00</published>
    <updated>2008-07-18T14:57:59.000-07:00</updated>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
      term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment'/>
    <title>Walking is fun</title>
    <content>I like it a lot.</content>
    <link rel='related' type='application/atom+xml'
      href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b?v=2'/>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html'
      href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTUVgYoeN_b'/>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml'
      href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZTUVgYoeN_b/comments/F53EAC190E4EA5C9?v=2'/>
    <author>
      <name>GoogleDevelopers</name>
      <uri>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers</uri>
    </author>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    ...
  </entry>
  ...
</feed>
```

source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments