# how to get youtube comment

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xH7vTWir9uU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is code to get youtube video to website.
The Question how to get video complete with comment?
Thanks

Comment: did you search stack overflow at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716005/embed-youtube-comments-and-like

Comment: I mean get the comment youtube to my website

Answer (score 1):

Unless you iframe the entire page I don't think there's an easy way to import the comments. Checkout the youtube data api v3 site. They have documentation on how you can use JS to grab comments from a page