# How do you embed comments from a YouTube video?

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, comments, embed

I'm displaying YouTube videos on my business website (see https://www.engelwrite.com/the-writers-practice-regimen-warm-up-read.html for an example -- password "comingsoon:)" ), and can't figure out how to embed YouTube comments below the vid. This is important because I encourage people to leave comments, and that engagement will help with YouTube ranking. Otherwise, I have to embed Facebook comments, which don't help my cause with YouTube.

I've looked around, and the best attempt at solving this problem was in 2013 here: [Getting Youtube Video Information using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194619/getting-youtube-video-information-using-javascript-jquery). Unfortunately, this method no longer works (unless I'm doing something incorrectly).

Another option has to do with YT's comment API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#usage, but I'm unclear on the implementation.

Does anyone know if it is possible to embed YT comments?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed youtube comments and like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716005/embed-youtube-comments-and-like)

Comment: Hi Austen, I came across that thread when I was researching, and neither of the answers solved my problem. The first is too vague--it simply recommends having a thorough knowledge of coding, which I don't yet have; and the second links to the same post I link to in my question, the solution to which no longer works. It does seem like I'll have to call on the comments api (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#usage), but beyond that, the details are unclear to me. Is there anyone who could explain that API interaction further? Can I implement that interaction with html?

Comment: HTML is just a markup language, it doesn't do anything on it's own. You will indeed need to do some coding with a language like JavaScript, PHP, or Python. The link you provided in your comment has code examples to use with their API.

Comment: Couldn't access your site because it is password protected. If you're using WordPress you can import the YouTube comments as WordPress comments. YouTube does not support embedding comments like it does the video.