# Embed youtube comments with a live streaming video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

Using some of the code I got here I was able to pull in comments on a regularly uploaded youtube video using JS and the Youtube API including title, author views and comments using the code found here:

[Stackoverflow answer used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194619/getting-youtube-video-information-using-javascript-jquery)

And my working example of a normally uploaded video:

[Working Static Video](http://xeroproject.com/test_noStream.html)

I have been trying to pull in a stream instead of a regularly uploaded video and the video itself is being pulled in great, but the rest of the info like the title and comments, which are the most important thing no longer show.

[Example Using a Youtube Stream](http://xeroproject.com/test.html)

I thought maybe it was because the stream was not live, but that doesn't seem to be the case since I can view the comments on a static page like any normal video its just positioned differently and I cant seem to find any info on the info having to be pulled in differently on a stream in the API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.